# Microsoft naming guidelines - What are "private interface members"?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, access-modifiers

From  the Microsoft Framework Design Guidelines:

> Casing and naming guidelines apply
>   only to public and protected
>   identifiers, and privately implemented
>   interface members. Teams are free to
>   choose their own guidelines for
>   internal and private identifiers.

What do they mean by a **privately implemented interface member**?

Comment: I would imagine it means private members that implement a declared interface member.

Comment: @nalroff: The naming guidelines for a member can't depend on whether that member implements an interface or not -- that would cause riots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it means [*explicitly*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) implemented interface members.

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense does it? If you allow someone to write `public void IMyInterface.doSomething() { }` then your interface must contain the incorrectly cased method signature `void doSomething()`. Now anyone who wants to implement that "publicly" also ends up with an incorrectly cased signature. You can't allow one without the other. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You can't make that public. Once you implement a method explicitly, you can't specify the privacy. So it would just be `void IMyInterface.doSomething()`

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: You are confused by the mistaken, it seems to me, inclusion of the word "privately". Replace it with "explicitly" and it makes sense (also, this means that it's going to be `void IMyInterface.DoSomething` with a capital `D` since it's certainly not `private`).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)